# Styling active anchor elements with css

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble to find a css solution for having an active anchor colored...

Why are the active anchors not red so that if clicked on "momo" momo keeps red? Or is active the wrong pseudoclass for that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:active{
        color:red;
        }
        a:hover{
        color:yellow;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul> Navigation
    <li class="subli"><a href="#momo">momo</a></li>
    <li class="subli"><a href="#ipsi">ipsi</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks
Juru

Comment: pseudo selectors have to used in this order:

a:link {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:visited {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:focus {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:hover {
  ⋮ declarations
}
a:active {
  ⋮ declarations
}

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:active` means "While being activated" e.g. when it is focused *and* the enter key is pressed or while it is hovered *and* the mouse button is being depressed. (Note that since you have have `:hover` after `:active` you'll always override it for mouse activates)

There is no pseudo-class for "Anchor with an href value that resolves to the current location". For that you need to need to modify the HTML (preferably before it gets to the browser, but you can use JS as well).

Answer (score 7):

Besides, you can use the [target pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#target-pseudo), which is pretty [well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) already, to style the element referenced by the anchor.

```
<a href="#this-element">Click here.<div>
<div id="this-element">It's going to be red.<div>

<style>
  #this-element:target{
    color:red;
  }
<style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use visited not active

a:visited {color:red;}

Active activates only onClick 
Visited stays red after you clicked

Comment: thanks for answering i actually need the active class. if not there are a couple liks read and not just the active  link localhost/test#momo

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order you have your styling setup for your anchor tags

Change this

```
    a:active{
    color:red;
    }
    a:hover{
    color:yellow;
    }
```

To this

```
    a:hover{
    color:yellow;
    }
    a:active{
    color:red;
    }
```

`:active` only occurs when you click and hold on the element or the element is focused and you hit enter.

If you want to show the active url as a different color you are going to have to add a class to the current active element and style that class with the color you want

Comment: your thinking of active in the wrong way.  `:active` only happens when you focus on the element such as a click

Answer (score 0):

The styles cascade, you need to switch them.

```
a:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
a:active {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

remove the `:active` property and just set `a{color:red}`