# all menu bar items getting same background color when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my below site, when I clicked on any menu tab,  the selected menu bar item color should be  `#1B3E70`.

**Prob is"**

Now whatever the menubar item selected, its getting background color: `#1B3E70` for each menu item which shouldn't be like that.. Only one selected menu bar item should have background color with : `#1B3E70`

**here is my site:**
[http://mywebsite.com/](http://test.adaptivestudios.com/)

Click the menubar items, then you'll understand the issue

Please suggest me what changes need to do..?

**EDIT:**
HERE IS JSFIDDLE: `http://jsfiddle.net/2s9Zm/1/`

Comment: Please create fiddle for your problem

Comment: Or post your HTML/JS/CSS right here.

Comment: The problem is that every anchor is getting "active" class whenever get clicked. The problem will be in jquery code. create fiddle of your problem as @MilindAnantwar said.

Comment: PLEASE KINDLY CHECK JSFIDDLE ABOVE IN MY POST.. i EDITED..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431835/styling-active-anchor-elements-with-css

Comment: @Robert : my issue is bit different, i already had a code, but not getting required output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-item a').click(function(){
        $('.menu-item a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Next time post a jsfiddle.

Comment: hey, still not working, please find my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2s9Zm/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#menu_id').css('background-color', '#1B3E70');
```

it will 100% work. If you are agree then please mark it as an answer so that other can use it as an reference